# SQL Using CASE to Apply WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I'm not sure if CASE is what I actually need to use here, but basically what I am trying to do is apply "WHERE ba.batchid = @batchId" but only if @batchId is not null.

Basically something like this, but this gives an error around the ba.batchid = '2' area ('2' is what the @batchId would come out to).

```
CASE WHEN '2' != '' THEN ba.batchid = '2' ELSE null END
```

Comment: `WHERE ba.batchid = @batchId AND @batchId IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I'd do `WHERE @batchid IS NULL or ba.batchid = @batchid`

Comment: *but this gives an error* - generally it's useful to provide the error.

Comment: I'd suggest also adding an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the solution @BillTürstandswithUkraine gives to avoid use of an inappropriate cached plan.

Comment: @BillTürstandswithUkraine Thanks that worked great! I just needed to add () around it so it came out to: AND (@batchId = '' or ba.batchid is null).

Comment: Suggest you read Erland's discussion of [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Presumably when your variable (parameter?) is NULL you want to include all rows; when it is not null you want to filter for that specific value.

Answer (score -1):

It helps to think of Case statements as a scalar value. The problem you are experiencing is caused by doing a comparison within the case statement. Basically, you need to pull the comparison out of the case statement.

I'm not sure of the logic you are trying to use, but the following syntax should be correct.

```
CASE WHEN '2' != '' THEN ba.batchid ELSE null END = '2'
```

Note that the = '2' is moved to the end. This way, the case statement will return batchid or null depending on the WHEN statement. This value is then compared to '2'.

Comment: `case` _expressions_, not statements. (Case _statements_ are used in stored procedured, for conditional execution of code.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
WHERE NULLIF(@batchId, '') IS NOT NULL AND ba.batchid = @batchid
```

First condition avoids empty('') as well as NULL with @batchid. Second will match the table value.

Answer (score -2):

Take it out of the SELECT part of your statement entirely and put it in the WHERE clause (after FROM)

```
WHERE ba.batchid = @batchId
  AND ba.batchid IS NOT NULL
```

Note that the AND ba.batchid IS NOT NULL is not necessary here as the first line will filter any nulls. However there are versions of SQL where this is not the case and retaining it in the query still works, hence I have left it in.

Comment: The `AND ba.batchid IS NOT NULL` is pointless. If `ba.batchid = @batchId` is true, then `ba.batchid` is by definition not `NULL`.

Comment: That is not true for all versions of SQL - hence I left it in. Not sure that was worthy of a downvote either - the answer still works.

Comment: It's true for every SQL Server version I can remember to; this behaviour was true since as long as SQL Server has supported ANSI `NULL`s, and if it *didn't* that pre-dates my usage of it (and if the OP is using SQL Server 2000, they have much bigger problems). There is **no** supported version of SQL Server where `ba.batchid = @batchId` can be true and `batchid` doesn't have a non-`NULL` value without turning off ANSI-`NULL`s; and that behaviour is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Question did not specify sql-server. The question is tagged with both SQL and SQL-server and I make no assumption because the user is  inexperienced. Either way you are splitting hairs unnecessarily, the answer still works.

Comment: *"Question did not specify sql-server."* Yes it does; it's in the tags. It's not splitting hairs, the: The `AND ba.batchid IS NOT NULL` is pointless.

Comment: So is SQL as my comment clearly pointed out and as I said, I make no assumption here because the user is clearly inexperienced. Honestly, there is no need for this negativity - I'm simply trying to help the requester.

Comment: SQL <> SQL Server. SQL is a query language. SQL Server is a RDBMS created by Microsoft and uses the SQL dialect T-SQL...